# trying to fetch data against id from database but not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch data against id and i want to pass last inserted id to another controller where i can fetch data against last inserted id.

```
  **this is sample code of insertion controller**

  
   $post_property = DB::table('post_property')->insert($data);
    
   $post_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

I want to pass $post_id to another controller where i can fetch against that id.

**here is the controller for fetching**

```
  class ShowPropController extends Controller
    {

      public function index()
       {
        $post_property = DB::table('post_property')->get();

        return view('single_view_buy')->with('post_property', $post_property);
        }
      }

   anyone please guide me.I shall be very thankful.
```

I tried different things but i am not getting any solution because i am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your route.

```
Route::get('/show-property/{id}', [ShowPropController::class, 'index']);
```

You must return the ID in your controller by calling the created route.

```
return redirect()->action([ShowPropController::class, 'index'], ['id' => $post_id]);
```

Modify the `index()` to accpe parameter

```
class ShowPropController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        $post_property = DB::table('post_property')->where('id', $id)->first();

        return view('single_view_buy', ['post_property' => $post_property]);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 01**

```
public function index() # set index back to normal

class ShowPropController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $post_property = DB::table('post_property')->where('id', $id)->first();

        return view('new_show_page', ['post_property' => $post_property]);
    }
}
```

In route

```
Route::get('/show-property/{id}', [ShowPropController::class, 'show']);
```

---

> **FYI: We do not come across situations like this. (very rare calling controller by another controller.) Revise your task once and get some idea of what you have to do exactly.**

Comment: what i am trying to do exactly is....I want to insert data into database and want to fetch data of that last inserted id

Comment: @Ali, I would suggest that once you create the record, redirect back to the index page or show  page as ideal

Comment: bro your solution worked...but now frontend disturbed after i applied your solution...how it come?

Comment: because your `index($id)` modified ?

Comment: instead of this `Route::get('/show-property/{id}', [ShowPropController::class, 'index']);` call create new method call `show` and pass it to there

Comment: ok..how frontend will be fixed then?

Comment: Create a new page to show and display the created data in there. Show page means View page

Comment: its already displaying in another page...data inserts from property.blade.php and displaying in single_view_buy.blade.php

Comment: can you guide me how to create new method call?

Comment: @Ali check the edit. Search product view page laravel in google you will get the idea